# Issue with jQuery .submit()

Tags: jquery, html

I'm having an issue submitting a form with jQuery's `submit()`.

I don't have any elements on my page with a name of `name="submit"` or `name="Submit"`, same goes for ID's.

My bit of jQuery code is as follows:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

    $(document).on('click', "#appSubmit",function(e){

            e.preventDefault();
            var value = $("#time").val();
            if(value == "--"){
                $( "#err-time" ).dialog( "open" );
            }else{
                alert("1");
                var dummy = $("#appSubmit").val();
                alert(dummy);
                $("#appSubmit").submit();
                alert("2");
            }

    });
});
```

All of the alerts work properly, even the `alert(dummy);` prints out the correct value. The `alert("2");` prints out, so it isn't even breaking on the `$("#appSubmit").submit();`

My submit button is

```
<input type="submit" name="appSubmit" id="appSubmit" value="Apply">
```

Any thoughts would be appreciated, thanks.

EDIT:

I'm sorry, I forgot to post an actual question.  The form isn't submitting when It hits the line `$("#appSubmit").submit();` in my code.  Nor does it break.

On the jQuery site the examples they give attached the event to the `<i+n+p+u+t type="submit">`, But I've tried it by trying to attach the event to the form's id and I still got the same behavior.  Passes the line with no breaking whatsoever.

The only way I can get it to work is if I use the basic javascript submit call `document.applySubmit.submit();`

Which is fine, and does the job.  But I'd still like to figure this out.

Edit 2:

I will try the .closest approach.  I didn't know what that was until now.  Thank you.  I will post if it worked.

Edit 3:

Was this question posted 3 times by me?  If so, I'm sorry.  I must not have been able to find my own question and assumed I never went though the whole question submission process and tried to post it properly a second/third time.

Edit:
Blazemonger suggestion worked.

Comment: I didn't get what is your issue...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't `.submit()` a button, you `.submit()` a form. Try:

```
$("#appSubmit").closest('form').submit();
```

or better yet:

```
$(this).closest('form').submit();
```

Comment: Yet another option is to only prevent the default behaviour of clicking on the button (in this case, submitting the form) when they don't want it to be submitted.